# Subconsultas en Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, subconsultas

¿Se puede hacer subconsultas en Access como la que pongo aquí?

```
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]SELECT 
ots.DESTINO, 
(SELECT e.DESTINO, Count(e.DIAENTRADA) AS entradas FROM ots AS e WHERE (((e.DIAENTRADA) Between #12/1/2018# And #12/31/2018#)) GROUP BY e.DESTINO ORDER BY e.DESTINO) as entradas,
(SELECT s.DESTINO, Count(s.DIASALIDA) AS entradas FROM ots AS s WHERE (((s.DIASALIDA) Between #12/1/2018# And #12/31/2018#)) GROUP BY s.DESTINO ORDER BY s.DESTINO) as salidas,
(SELECT p.DESTINO, sum([p]![DIASALIDA]-[p]![DIAPREVIST]) AS puntualidad FROM ots as p WHERE (((p.DIASALIDA) Between #12/01/2018# And #12/31/2018#)) GROUP BY p.DESTINO ORDER BY p.DESTINO) as puntualidad,
(SELECT r.DESTINO, sum([r]![DIASALIDA]-[r]![DIAENTRADA]) AS respuesta FROM ots as r WHERE (((r.DIASALIDA) Between #12/01/2018# And #12/31/2018#)) GROUP BY r.DESTINO ORDER BY r.DESTINO) as respuesta
FROM ots
ORDER BY ots.DESTINO;
```

Error que da:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Soy bastante novato en Access.

Comment: no veo porque no.. tuviste algun problema?

Comment: Cuando la ejecuto me dice que puede devolver como maximo un registro.

Comment: el error debe estar escrito en la pregunta. alguna de esas subconsultas devuelve mas de un registro? igual, no tiene mucho sentido ese group by, si no estas usando ningun campo para agrupar, las subconsultas son todas planas y no tienen una condicion que dependa del destino...

Comment: Tienes razón, las agrupaciones, son por destino, pero individuales, las subconsultas son individuales y cada subconsulta puede devolver un nunero diferente de registros, quizas debería crear 4 consultas independientes, luego quiero pasar estos datos a un informe.

Comment: He modificado la pregunta y la consulta y he añadido un pantallazo del error que da ahora.

Comment: y ahora toda tu consulta esta mal.. a ver.. La db se maneja de a un registro por ver. O sea que si tu subconsulta esta en el select, debe si o si devolver un solo registro. Obviamente, tu cambio hace que no solo no devuelva un solo registro, si no que esa subconsulta que armaste esta mal. Te recomendaria, que vayas paso a paso y primero soluciones los datos que queres obtener en cada linea, y despues trates de juntarlo.

Comment: Ya modifique las subconsultas, que individualmente funcionan cada una, pero ahora me pide que ponga la palabra EXISTS delantate de las subconsultas, si hago eso me devuelve tantos registros como registros hay en la tabla y con unos valores que no tienen sentido.